# Make Ws-Federation authentication with OWIN working with server on differents domains

Tags: c#, owin, adfs2.0, ws-federation

Context:

- 1 Web server: IIS with website https://WebApp.g1.my-web-domain.com (real certificate bought). Server is on domain my-web-domain.com
- 1 Test ADFS server (2.0): adfs metadata: https://fs.vt.test/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml (self-signed certificate)
- 1 Test client in vt.test domain

Working:

- I Install website on the same server as the ADFS (fs.vt.test) and it works.

Wanted:

- ADFS is a way to authenticate client on tiers app and this is my case.
  If I try my app on server my-app-domain.com and Owin failed to authenticate me.

Just a silent failed, nothing in events of ADFS and no exception or http errors ...

I tried a lot of config for OWIN, this my last code:

```
app.SetLoggerFactory(new NLogFactory());
        app.UseErrorPage(new ErrorPageOptions()
        {
            //Shows the OWIN environment dictionary keys and values. This detail is enabled by default if you are running your app from VS unless disabled in code. 
            ShowEnvironment = true,
            //Hides cookie details
            ShowCookies = false,
            //Shows the lines of code throwing this exception. This detail is enabled by default if you are running your app from VS unless disabled in code. 
            ShowSourceCode = true,
        });
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager(container.GetInstance<ILoggingService>())
        });

        app.Use(async (Context, next) =>
        {
            new NLogLoggingService("Owin after cookie log").Debug(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Context.Authentication, Formatting.None,
                    new JsonSerializerSettings()
                    {
                        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                    }));
            await next.Invoke();
            new NLogLoggingService("Owin after cookie log").Debug(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Context.Authentication, Formatting.None,
                    new JsonSerializerSettings()
                    {
                        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                    }));
        });
        //AppBuilderLoggerExtensions
        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
            new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Wtrealm = realm,
                MetadataAddress = adfsMetadata,
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
                Notifications = new WsFederationAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Redirect("Home/Unauthorized?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
});

        app.Use(async (Context, next) =>
        {
            new NLogLoggingService("Owin after federation log").Debug(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Context.Authentication, Formatting.None,
                     new JsonSerializerSettings()
                     {
                         ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                     }));
            await next.Invoke();
            new NLogLoggingService("Owin after federation log").Debug(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Context.Authentication, Formatting.None,
                    new JsonSerializerSettings()
                    {
                        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                    }));
        });
        // This makes any middleware defined above this line run before the Authorization rule is applied in web.config
        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
```

I follow a post like this one to configure my party trust in ADFS management:
http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/

and my config is:

- ida:ADFSMetadata: https://fs.vt.test/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml"
- ida:Wtrealm: https://WebApp.g1.my-web-domain.com/"

I have been searching blogs, stackoverflow  for a few days but I can't make my authentication work. Maybe a certificate issue or ...

I can't find a way to debug what is wrong with my configuration.

I don't have anything from OWIN in my Nlog.

Comment: Try wireshark and put await within a try catch block, because the error message might get swallowed. I also followed this tut you mentioned above, my code works, but in my case both virtual machines are in the same domain.Perhaps this [link](https://migration-blog.com/2015/11/26/adfs-how-to-enable-trace-debugging-and-advanced-access-logging/) might also help debugging the auth problem.